# Can receive but cannot send SMS on SGS3, help me debug with logcat?

Tags: sms, samsung-galaxy-s-3, logging, mms, apn

For a couple months now (during which time I've tried ~20 ROMs), I can receive & make calls fine, receive & send emails fine, sync fine, everything is fine except I cannot send SMS. I've tried HandCent but it didn't work either. I have 15 seconds of logcat I can't understand at all - can someone help?

And is this the best way to isolate the problem or should I be trying something else?

<sup>(click image to enlarge)</sup>

[image: logcat /dev/log/system]

*Edited to add confusing APN logcat messages.*

[image]

Why does it want to get Neighboring Cell IDS? There are hundreds or thousands of messages where it tries but gets denied. Is this like a worm attempt being blocked?

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

With those APN=null messages, does that confirm your concerns about it being an APN issue after all?

Comment: I don't completely understand the log, but I see a lot of "Mms:app" appearing. Are you sure you are sending smses and not mmses? Next to that, some general suggestions: are you sure the number of your provider is correct? Maybe you should check with your provider, maybe it is a problem on their side? Was everything working correctly before on your stock Android OS? When did you start having these problems? etcera

Comment: Hi I'm just using the Stock Messaging App **Messaging** _version 4.2.1-eng.bajee11.20130213.072212_ - I presume it sends both SMS and MMS but I'm not sure I've sent an MMS in my life. Number of provider? They gave me a "Messaging Center" number but I don't know where I'm supposed to enter it; there's no field in the App settings or the Systems settings that I can see. I had a problems on my stock Samsung BloatBean which wouldn't update OTA but the SMS problem didn't start when I rooted my phone, but during one of the many ROM changes (no idea which one, but doesn't work for any ROM now).

Comment: How many characters had the message you've tried to send? Any pictures included or files attached?

Comment: Thx for the edit @Izzy - I've just tried a few standard words, nothing over 30 characters. No pictures or files, but that would turn it MMS  I imagine. Might just try to send a picture....

Comment: That was the intention of my question, hence fully answered: Unless you *explicitly* said it should be sent as MMS, *that* should have been a SMS (less than 160 bytes, no attachments). But a buggy app might not care. Any "bill" you could consult (unlikely if the messages really did not make it)? As for the edit: Gladly helped. Saves a little scrolling :)

Comment: @Izzy So you've had an inspired moment and - amazingly - my MMSs get through but my SMSs fail. I owe you a debt of gratitude already as, although it's inconvenient, I can turn every SMS into an MMS but this should make the problem extremely isolated no?

Comment: Which means you've tried to explicitly send an MMS and it worked? So we can rule out SMS might be converted to MMS and sending then fails due to missing/wrong MMS-APN? I don't think it will really help, but is worth a try: using a 3rd party SMS app to see whether the "generic failure" is caused by the app (and not the service).

Comment: @Izzy That's correct. All MMS go through but all SMS instantly fail. I've used a couple 3rd party SMS apps and the same thing occurs; MMS goes through but SMS instantly fails. So this means the "generic failure" is caused by my service provider?

I see a heck of a lot of logcat error(?) messages about this MMS-APN you mention; I might see if I can add the screenshots to my OP as there seems to be some chaos in my logs.

Comment: You could also place an excerpt of your logcat at e.g. [PateBin](http://pastebin.com/) and link it to your OP, that's easier to handle/read than images of it. Also, you might contact your provider with those details and have him send you a service SMS for configuration (your device then will automatically pick the data from the SMS and adjust its configuration, hopefully).

Comment: Ah sorry I was presuming the reverse re: "easier to read" 55. The thing is my logcat is like 60,000 lines after a day; it's doing my head in with too much information of which I understand very little. When I Pastebin should I filter for specific keywords or...

Would changing service providers be expected to result in a fix? Cause AIS is totally unsympathetic and belligerent, saying *"You root your phone, your problem"*; which I do empathize with but they load it up with 200 bloatware apps so (in Toddler voice) *"They Started It!"*